# What is my Gateway?

Tags: router, ipv4, gateway

My wireless router has these items when I set it up, but I don't know the Gateway number.

- IP Address `192.168.1.100`
- Subnet Mask `255.255.255.0`
- DNS Server `192.168.1.1`
- Secondary DNS Server `0.0.0.0`

It sometimes says "*Invalid gateway address. Gateway address must be on the same subnet with the network and the host number cannot be all 0 or all 1 binary values.*"

In this case what is the Gateway?

Comment: Are you configuring the router _itself_, or a computer that'll be connected to the router?

Comment: The router gateway is the IP address of the upstream gateway (router) belonging to your ISP. Your ISP should provide that address automatically when your internet is running.

Comment: Your question was difficult to understand so I added formatting and corrected some wording. Please check that my edits are valid.

Comment: Where are you getting this information from?  I mean, how are you seeing this?  In your netork settings, a website, an app, ipconfig? The information you are showing for IP address and DNS server don't make sense for your router's settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but based on what I am guessing you are asking, you should be using a gateway address of 192.168.1.1, with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

Don't hold me to that, as I am filling in a lot of blanks here. :)

Answer (score 0):

> *ipconfig /all*

Write it to cmd and you can find your all network details.